# Правильный запрос MySQLi

Tags: mysqli, запрос, mysql

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как правильно выполнить такой запрос:

```
$zapros=mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * FROM table WHERE price='30.33'");
```

В ответ получаем пустой массив, думаю проблема в числе с точкой, как его правильно вставить? Или нужно изменить столбик в БД? Сейчас он float, спасибо

Comment: а вы в phpmyadmin попробуйте. что выдаст вам запрос

Comment: Попробуйте без кавычек.

Comment: Нечего, MySQL вернула пустой результат (т.е. ноль строк). ( Запрос занял 0.0006 сек. )

SELECT * 
FROM  `sklad_partiya_komponenty` 
WHERE  `price` =  '303.3'
LIMIT 0 , 30

и без кавычек ничего

Comment: то же самое, ноль результатов

Comment: Ошибки никакой нет, просто ноль результатов

Comment: Если поменять столбик на варчар то все нормально, но это не дело

Comment: Если поменять столбик на варчар то все нормально, но это не дело

Comment: попробуй так: SELECT * FROM sklad_partiya_komponenty WHERE  price+"0.00" = '303.3' LIMIT 0 , 30 только price в наклонные кавычки возми

Comment: написал так SELECT * FROM `sklad_partiya_komponenty` WHERE `price`+"0.00" = '303.3'  0 результатов

Comment: с кавычками, тут что-то вырезает их редактор

Comment: Структуру таблицы покажите.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С типом float не получится. Есть несколько вариантов решения.

1. Сделать поле типа decimal тогда запрос будет выглядеть так:

   SELECT * FROM table WHERE price=cast('30.33' as decimal(2,2))
2. Выбирать через LIKE

   SELECT * FROM table WHERE price LIKE 30.33

Comment: а если сделать поле типо Varchar возможны ли какие либо трудности в дальнейшем?

Comment: FLK, а почему не получается с "float"? Точность числа? 

benjibboy, "а если сделать поле типа Varchar возможны ли какие либо трудности в дальнейшем?" 

Да возможны. Т.к. нужно будет постоянно переводить varchar в  decimal при сортировке.Но:
SELECT * FROM sklad_partiya_komponenty WHERE price+"0.00" = '303.3' мне как раз это решение и помогло. Я хранил разные характеристики товаров разных типов в одном столбце текст. и при выборке таким образом приводил к нужному типу.

Comment: Да, и не только при сортировке. При сравнении тоже. Да везде будут проблемы. Только что вы прямую выборку по точному совпадению сделаете.
А лучше используйте поле типа decemial! никаких проблем не будет.
Для этого поля число: 150 и 150.00 одинаковы

Comment: Спасибо, действительно поле сделал decimal 10,2 и нормально теперь выбирает, просто не хотел менять запросы, а то много переделывать пришлось бы, а теперь и так все работает, еще раз спасибо Виктор

Comment: @Victor Halauko если интересно почему да как рекомендую: [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-float.html)